# Как работает сервер...?

Tags: php, java, сервер, хостинг

Всем привет. Обьясните пожалуйста мне некоторые вещи. Вот есть у меня локальный сервак, пишу его на SparkJava... И получается сервер можно собрать в jar архив. Далее я пишу сервер на php и могу скидывать php-скрипты.

Оба сервера по сути допустимы но как они могут работать в интернете? Как сервер работает на хостинге на разных языках? Как запустить jar если сервер не у меня дома? Как все это работает?(

Comment: Сервер в смысле железки - это просто компьютер, и всё на нём запускается и работает абсолютно так же, как и на домашнем компьютере

Comment: На shared-хостингах полный доступ к серверу (в смысле железки) не дают, там обычно стоит какой-нибудь Apache, который запускает скрипты пользователя. На VDS и дедиках теоретически может стоять самая обыкновенная винда, показывающая самый обыкновенный рабочий стол и позволяющая творить что угодно как на домашнем компе

Comment: @andreymal, и.. Снова ничего не понятно. 4 года уже туплю а тут все минусуют и минусуют

Comment: Какое именно слово непонятно? «Сервер — это просто компьютер» тоже непонятно?)

Comment: @andreymal, нет. Я не понимаю почему на хостинге скрипты работают

Comment: Потому что админ туда Apache установил

Comment: @andreymal, видимо мне надо разобраться в корнях веба прежде чем лезть туда

Comment: Просто установите и настройте Apache на своём собственном компьютере :) Можно вместе с каким-нибудь XAMPP или аналогом для удобства

Comment: «Как запустить jar если сервер не у меня дома?» — взять VDS или дедик, поставить туда джаву как обычно и запустить на ней jar как обычно :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Без интерпретатора ничего не будет работать, нужна машина которая будет запускать код `JAR`, и опять же, если сервер на `php`, то там есть сервер либо `LAMP`, либо другой, тот же `node.js`. И самое интересное, два сервера вместе работать никогда не будут, так как есть конфиги, единые конфиги. Они предназначены только для одного сервера.

По поводу как работает на хостинге. Очень просто. Почему вы решили что на хостинге один сервер? Их много, та же технология VPS чего стоит, или например, используются докеры ака кубернеты.

Comment: Но вот я помню мне давали админку и я закидывал туда php скрипты (на сайт). А потом надо было .jar запустить. И я не смог это сделать

Comment: @Flippy, и не будет, это PHP хостинг, там не запустите ничего просто так, без интерпретатора не получится, ещё раз говорю. Если хотите реализовать то нужен `VPS` сервер. Там устанавливаете `Java Open JDK`, а потом в PHP даёте команду шеллу что нужно запустить через `Java`.